# Playing audio using the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I'm introducing a functionality in my iPhone app that allows user to mix and play selected audio files.

What is the difference between just using two AVAudioPlayer to play the music files concurrently versus using Apple's example class, MixerHost, to play the files?

The class MixerHost can be found on here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Listings/Classes_MixerHostAudio_h.html

Answer (score 0):

MixerHost gives you much more precise control over the relative timing of the two audio inputs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relative timing benefit. Also in terms of the quality of the mixed sound, is MixerHost much better? Thanks